# What is the relation between $\vert (u(x), v(x))\vert$ and $\vert u(x)\vert, \vert v(x)\vert$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, geometry

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $u, v:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be two functions. Let $\alpha\geq 1$. There is a relation between $\vert u(x), v(x)\vert^{\alpha}$ and $\vert u(x)\vert, \vert v(x)\vert$, maybe to some power?
I mean, does some inequality of the type
$$\vert (u(x), v(x))\vert^{\alpha} \lessgtr \vert u(x)\vert^{\alpha_1}\vert v(x)\vert^{\alpha_2},$$
hold for some coefficients $\alpha_1, \alpha_2?$

EDIT: To be clear, $( u(x), v(x))\in\mathbb{R}^2$, so $\vert (u(x), v(x))\vert$ denotes the modulus of the vector $(u(x), v(x))$.

Could anyone help or give some references?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does the notation $|u(x),v(x)|$ mean?

Comment: Sorry, I mean $\vert (u(x), v(x))\vert^{\alpha}$, I edited the question.

Comment: You have
$$
|(u(x),v(x))|^{2\alpha} = (u(x)^2 + v(x)^2)^\alpha.
$$
Then, you can just use $a^2 + b^2 \geq 2ab$ and obtain
$$
|(u(x),v(x))|^{2\alpha} \geq 2^\alpha u(x)^{\alpha} v(x)^{\alpha}.
$$
Taking square roots and since $\alpha \geq 1$
$$
|(u(x),v(x))|^{\alpha} \geq 2^{\alpha/2} |u(x)|^{\alpha/2} |v(x)|^{\alpha/2} \geq  |u(x)|^{\alpha/2} |v(x)|^{\alpha/2}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much @G.Gare, if you write it as answer I will accept it. Thank you again!

Comment: @C.Bishop it's done! By the way, there are for sure more and more things you can do

Comment: Maybe it is more appropriate to ask for a new question.

Comment: @G.Gare I might as well to ask you for an opinion. There is some way to obtain an inequality of the type $$\vert (u(x), v(x))\vert^{\alpha}\geq \vert u(x)\vert^{\alpha_1} + \vert v(x)\vert^{\alpha_2}?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$
|((),())|^{2}=(()^2+()^2)^.
$$
Then, you can just use $^2+^2≥2$ and obtain
$$
|((),())|^{2}≥2^\alpha()^()^.
$$
Taking square roots and since $\geq 1$,
$$
|((),())|^≥2^{/2}|()|^{/2}|()|^{/2}≥|()|^{/2}|()|^{/2}
$$